# Display none in CSS fade out does not work or hide the div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, fadein

I have the following CSS transition -

```css
fadeinout-animate {
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
    animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
    opacity: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeinout {
  50% { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fadeinout {
  50% { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fadeinout {
  100% { opacity: 0;display:none; }
}
```

But, when I add this class to a div in Angular template, display none works but a blank space of 200*200 stays as is. (If I inspect element I still see that the red background alone is gone but manually applying display none inline style in browser hides or removes div) If i make height:0 that div goes off but it impacts behavior. How do I fix it?

Comment: where is display;none ?

Comment: `visibility: hidden;`

Comment: Please create a [MCVE] so we can see your problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to @Highdef answer,.

If you don't mind adding a bit of Javascript, you can listen for the animation end event, and set display none manually.

```js
const e = document.getElementById("a");
e.addEventListener("animationend", (ev) => {
  if (ev.type === "animationend") {
    e.style.display = "none";
  }
}, false);
```

```css
#a {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
  animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes fadeinout {
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="border:1px solid black;width:200px;">
  <div id="a">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

CSS can't animate between **display: none**; and **display: block**;. Worse yet: it can't animate between height: 0 and height: auto.
So you need to hard code the height.

**Here's an attempt with CSS:**

*Expected: the border should collapse but will it?*

```css
#a {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
  animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes fadeinout {
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="border:1px solid black;width:200px;">
  <div id="a">
  </div>
</div>
```

*Output: No, it won't.*

**Now, lets try this..**

```css
#a {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
  animation: fadeinout 4s linear forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes fadeinout {
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 200px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="border:1px solid black;width:200px;">
  <div id="a">
  </div>
</div>
```

*So, we basically collapsed the div after its transition was over by reducing its height to 0 and thus the parent container tag collapsed.*